# Resolution changes after startup/login

Tags: gnome, nvidia, xorg, display-resolution, ubuntu-gnome

I have been trying to use Gnome 3.8 / 3.10 / 3.12 since Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 and no matter what I do it **changes the screen resolution** to **720p**, instead of **1080p**, so I have to **manually set 1080p every time I start the PC**!

Card: Nvidia GTX 550
Driver: all available
Distro: Ubuntu 13.10 / 14.04
Gnome Shell: 3.8 / 3.10 / 3.12

**Things I tried so far:**

- opening nvidia-settings as root and user
- changing settings in nvidia-settings= force Powermizer to Maximum / OpenGL settings / Quality Settings - (I have done it all)
- forcing nvidia-settings to load on startup (Startup Aplications)
- adding/deleting/changing xorg.conf = "modes" / "metamodes" / "Display" / "EDID" - (I have done it all)
- adding gdm/init = xrandr output DVI-D-0 --mode
- installing different Kernels = 3.10 / 3.12 / 3.13 / 3.14
- installing different Nvidia Drivers= all available for Ubuntu
- installing Lightdm/MDM = everything breaks down
- changing cables = DVI / HDMI
- blocking/changing EDID = blocking the extensions on EDID (maybe the hdmi sound was causing the problem) / "noEDID"- system looses all resolutions

What I learned so far:

- Whenever I try to force 1080p by adding a command to xorg/gdm/xrandr the screen changes to 1080p for 1sec and then goes back to 720p! ... : (
- Tested Xubuntu/Kubuntu 14.04 = no resolution problems, just the usual terrible Nvidia performance (no vsync, no vdpau)
- Just installed Linux Mint yesterday and this problem doesn't happen (MDM), 1080p since the login screen.
- Tested Gnome 3.10/3.12 on the latest Fedora / Suse / Antergos and the problem persists!

Possible causes:

- Xserver 3.15 / 3.13 = I tried to replace ubuntu 14.04 xserver (3.15) with ubuntu 12.02 (3.13) cheating the repos and the whole system melted down!
- I really want Gnome 3 and a supported version of Ubuntu (I am stuck at 13.04)!
- I am very persistent and have problems taking NO for an answer!
- I had an ATI HD 4x series and I saved money to buy this Nvidia because gaming on Linux became impossible (missing GL extensions on Legacy drivers)... so .... thinking that it would solve all the video issues I had on Linux with ATI ... but ... how wrong was I ???? Now I have problems with basic functionalities (RESOLUTION / VSYNC / VDPAU) !

....I started using Linux 3 years ago and all these GPUs mess have been a nightmare in my Linux experience! 
....It's what makes me think about giving up Linux for all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not specify whether you saved your settings to the X configuration file (`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`) using `nvidia-settings`. That should solve this. Just open `nvidia-settings` as `root`:

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

Then, choose the right settings and click on the "Save to X Configuration" button:

[image]

---

If this does not work, there is something else overwriting your settings. Probably your desktop environment. As a workaround, you can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 10
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --mode 1920x1080 
echo "Script was run"
```

The `sleep` is needed to make sure that the Desktop Environment has finished starting before the script is run. That way, you know that it will be run *after* the DE has reconfigured your screens. Make the script executable and add it to your startup applications. That should do the trick.

Comment: @user282534 OK, in that case it sounds like something is overwriting your settings. Presumably the Gnome Display settings thingie. Did you have a look at the answer I linked to? A possible workaround would be to write a script that uses `xrandr` to set your desired settings and add that script to your session startup files. I'd be happy to write the script for you if you add the output of `xrandr` (once you have chosen the right settings) to your question.

Comment: Hi terdon, first of all thanks for answering...                                                                                           1 ° - I did click on the "Save to X Configuration" button many times, running nvidia-settings as SUDO, as GKSUDO, editing xorg.conf manually as root.... | 2° - Xrandr lists all resolutions available, including 1920x1080, but the one marked as "preferred" is 12080x720 | 3° - When I log in the screen flashes on 1080p (after tweaking xorg.conf / gdm init.conf, xprofile, monitors.xml) and goes back to 720p.

Comment: @user282534 yes, I know. Creating a script that runs the right xrandr command should fix this. It ain't elegant but it should work. Please [edit] your question and add the output of `xrandr` _after_ setting the desired resolution and I will write a script for you that calls the right command. The flashing is because you have the desired resolution set (presumably in `xorg.conf`) but Gnome in its infinite wisdom is then overwriting it.

Comment: Hi terdon,..... 1° - I did try to use a script forcing xrandr to output 1080p and add it to the Startup Aplications... and it does at one point, but then something bypass all that and sets the screen to 720p.... Is there more modules involved on this besides GDM / X11 /Nvidia? | 2° - Is it possible that there is a command  on GDM forcing the EDID "preferred" mode no matter what?

Comment: @user282534 1) did you add it to GDM's startup applications or yours? 2) Try adding `sleep 10` to your script, _before_ the `xrandr` command. That will cause it to wait 10 seconds before running it. Assuming something else is re-setting the resolution after you login, adding the delay should cause the script to be run _afterwards_ and avoid the problem. 3) Yes, Gnome is also involved, I'm pretty sure that's what's causing you pain. Have you actually tried setting the resolution through gnome's settings instead of nvidia-settings?

Comment: Hi terdon, .... 1° - I add the script to Startup Applications on the Apps menu and also on the xprofile and gdm init.config.... | 2° - I haven't tried the "Sleep 10" delay... I give it a shot! ... so the command will like like this: "sleep 10 xrandr --output ...." right? |  3° - Is there a way to change the Gnome settings that might be changing the resolution? like a Registry Editor? Or a .config ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14602/discussion-between-terdon-and-user282534).

Comment: Come into the chat room so we can discuss this more easily. And no, you need the `sleep 10` and `xrandr` commands on separate lines or separated by a semicolon (`;`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14605/discussion-between-user282534-and-terdon).

Comment: Thanks to terdon Script and the magical "Sleep 10" trick now I can finally use Gnome!!!! : )

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. While using Optimus Manager (alternative to NVIDIA Prime), i was playing a game normally. I changed some in-game graphic settings and it crashed, due to which i had to reboot linux and then the resolution changed as soon i logged in ( after the login screen). I spend endless time fixing it using **xrandr** and other stuffs but failed. I later found out **nvidia-settings** and **optimus-manager** generates its own **xorg.conf**.

So a quick and efficient solution was very simple and was as follows:

Delete:

> /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Delete unnecessary configuration files:

> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/

e.g:

> 10-optimus-manager.conf

I then rebooted and all became back to normal.