# Display not using xorg.conf?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xorg, display, resolution

How can I force my PC to use the xorg.conf file ?
I have it set up correctly and it is located at etc/x11/xorg.conf but it is ignored by at start up, I know the file is valid as I created it using nvidia-settings.
I just do not know why it is been ignored.

Thanks for any help

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Vestel 40 FHD_LCD-TV"
    HorizSync       15.0 - 46.0
    VertRefresh     49.0 - 61.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 650"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080_60 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: What makes you think it is being ignored ? Typically you need to run nvidia-settings as root and save the configuration.

Comment: I have it set up to use 1920x1080p but every time I start the pC it sets the display to the (native) 1080i and I have to manualy set it to 1920x1080p every time. It may not seem like a big deal but causes screen tearing in videos etc....

Comment: did you run nvidia-settings as root and save the settings ?

Comment: Yes I don't know what happend it is just not been recognized

Comment: post your xorg.conf

Comment: Is there a terminal command for switching between progressive and interlaced scanning. I could add this to a shell script and run at boot. This would be an acceptable workaround. I tried to Google it but it was difficult to format a question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Gnome Shell: 3.8 / 3.10 / 3.12:

From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/468312/158442):

> If this does not work, there is something else overwriting your
>   settings. Probably your desktop environment. As a workaround, you can
>   use this script:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> sleep 10
> xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --mode 1920x1080 
> echo "Script was run"
> ```
>
> The `sleep` is needed to make sure that the Desktop Environment has
>   finished starting before the script is run. That way, you know that it
>   will be run *after* the DE has reconfigured your screens. Make the
>   script executable and add it to your startup applications. That should
>   do the trick.