# Ubuntu 14.04 wont allow me to change my screen resolution to 1920x1080

Tags: resolution, screen

I have recently moved from Windows to Ubuntu and I’m having a problem that has been troubling me all day. I have a Samsung SyncMaster S22B300 Monitor which supports up to 1920x1080 resolution and it is connected to my computer through a Nvidia GTX 650 Ti boost graphics card. I've tried various drivers and none of them allow me to run Ubuntu in full 1920x1080 resolution. I'm sorry if this has been answered loads of times and I would really appreciate it if someone could direct me to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Gnome Shell: 3.8 / 3.10 / 3.12:

- If this does not work, there is something else overwriting your settings. Probably your desktop environment. As a workaround, you can use this script:

`#!/bin/bash sleep 10 xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --mode 1920x1080 echo "Script was run"`

The sleep is needed to make sure that the Desktop Environment has finished starting before the script is run. That way, you know that it will be run after the DE has reconfigured your screens. Make the script executable and add it to your startup applications. That should do the trick.

The full answer is here: [Resolution changes after startup/login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468298/resolution-changes-after-startup-login)

**P.S.  After Ubuntu 12.04 GTX 650 has been a nightmare! ... I am stuck at "tearing video" issues.**